# Discovering data type of incoming socket data in python

Tags: python, sockets, types

There are couple of devices which are sending socket data over *TCP/IP* to socket server. Some of the devices are sending data as *Binary encoded Hexadecimal string*, others are *ASCII string*.

Eg.;

If device sending data in *ASCII string* type, script is begin to process immediately without any conversion.

If device sending *Binary encoded HEX string*, script should has to convert *Binary encoded Hex string* into *Hex string* first with;

```
data = binascii.hexlify(data)
```

There are two scripts running for different data types for that simple single line. But, I think this could be done in one script if script be aware of the incoming data type. Is there a way to discover type of the incoming socket data in Python?

Comment: Hex strings are subset of ascii strings, you cannot always tell the type for sure. If possible, provide two TCP ports (or two IP addresses) on the server, one for each client group.

Answer (score 1):

If you can you should make the sending devices signal what data they are sending eg by using different TCP ports or prepending each message with an `"h"` for hex or an `"a"` for ascii - possibly even use an established protocol like [XML-RPC](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xmlrpc.html)

Actually you can only be sure in *some* cases as all hex-encoded strings are valid ascii and some ascii-strings are valid hex like `"CAFE"`.
You can make sure you can decode a string as hex with

```
import string
def is_possibly_hex(s):
    return all(c in string.hexdigits for c in s)
```

or

```
import binascii
def is_possibly_hex(s):
    try:
        binascii.unhexlify(s)
    except binascii.Error:
        return False
    return True
```